How does Mysql determine when to use a unique index or a composite index?
 CREATE TABLE `yonghu` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '??',
  `addtime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT '????',
  `zhanghao` varchar(200) NOT NULL COMMENT '??',
  `mima` varchar(200) NOT NULL COMMENT '??',
  `xingming` varchar(200) NOT NULL COMMENT '??',
  `xingbie` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '??',
  `lianxidianhua` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '????',
  `member` int DEFAULT '0',
  `discounts` int DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `zhanghao` (`zhanghao`),
  KEY `idx_zhanghao_member` (`zhanghao`,`member`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1707209867641 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3 COMMENT='??'

I have a yonghu table. The zhanghao field is a unique index and I created a composite index using zhanghao and member fields. In the following SQL, I feel that a composite index should be used faster. Why does Mysql choose to use a unique index?
mysql> EXPLAIN select member from yonghu where zhanghao ="asd";
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+------------------------------+----------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type  | possible_keys                | key      | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+------------------------------+----------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | yonghu | NULL       | const | zhanghao,idx_zhanghao_member | zhanghao | 602     | const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+------------------------------+----------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

I will use the composite index after deleting the zhanghao unique index, and the type of explain is ·ref· and the type of the unique index is ·const· From the type point of view, it is still a unique index. Doesn't the composite index not need to return the table? Shouldn't it be faster?
mysql> EXPLAIN select addtime from yonghu where zhanghao ="asd";
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table  | partitions | type | possible_keys       | key                 | key_len | ref   | rows | filtered | Extra |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | yonghu | NULL       | ref  | idx_zhanghao_member | idx_zhanghao_member | 602     | const |    1 |   100.00 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+-------+------+----------+-------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)


how many rows in your table?

10 rows of data @lant

Generally speaking, if the index cover the field, as you say,it's doesn't need to return the table to query ohter field.
But, if there is a unique index,and the sql is a = query, use unique index is a better choice. Because if the value to be queried is found in the unique index, there is no need to continue scanning and indexing the remaining index, but if using other index, need to continue scanning until other value appearing.
Also,  unique index and = query means there will be no more than one row of data that satisfies, so event if need to return the table, it is still very fast and there will be no significant performance difference.
If your sql is a range query like select member from yonghu where zhanghao >"asd"; it will use idx_zhanghao_member, if using unique index it will return to table, so it's less efficient than covering index.
BTW, if you want to verify the efficiency of index execution, you need to prepare more data, because Indexes are less important for queries on small tables, or big tables where report queries process most or all of the rows.
